# SharePoint Foundation 2010 - Unable to change Site Theme

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error, site-template, theme

I'm having trouble changing the site theme in my SharePoint Foundation 2010 environment.

When I do Site Actions > Site Settings > Look and Feel > Site Theme, i receive:

Error: Access Denied

I currently have Full Control over the site.

When verifying the User Permissions in Central Administration, I can see that All Permissions are enabled (including "Apply themes and borders").

I can find nothing in my ULS logs concerning this.

There is not a single site where I can change the Site Theme.

Please advise.

---

After fiddling with the permissions I managed to reach the theme selection page on 1 subsite. But after selecting any theme for that site I receive the error:

Error
Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
Correlation ID: x

When I filter for the Correlation ID I see 3 messages:

- Name=Request (POST:http://URL/Site/TestSite1/_layouts/themeweb.aspx)
- Site=/
- Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://URL/Site/TestSite1/_layouts/themeweb.aspx)). Execution Time=43.8902150971702

These messages aren't very useful.

All the other sites still give me the Acces Denied error.

Comment: Have you tried an IIS Reset or an AppPool recycle?

Comment: @Dandroid - I've done an IIS reset and AppPool recycle, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was performing a Site Collection backup and restore to a new web application in a new content database. It turned out that the old Content Database belonged to the devil.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting yourself as Site Collection administrator and retry.

Comment: I've added myself as Site Collection Administrator. I'm still unable to change the Site Theme. I've performed an IIS reset aswell. No joy.

Comment: Same happens on site collection ROOT site as well?

Comment: The same error occurs on the site collection root as well.